# STS in ubuntu 14.04 not getting started

Tags: spring, ubuntu-14.04, spring-tool-suite

Started STS using terminal in ubuntu 14.04 (./STS) and it turns white blank and didn't get started. And at terminal gets this info - 
**org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized**.

I am using Open JDK7 (1.7.0_65), STS - 3.6.1 and Ubuntu - 14.04 all 64 bit. Didn't get any log too. 
Please tell what to do?

Comment: I have not seen this problem, what version of STS are you using? I always use Sun/Oracle JDK though. Maybe try that. While openJDK may have nicer open licenses, Sun/Oracle JDK tends to work better. So maybe try installing sun jdk. Its quite easy using ppa (http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html).

Comment: I just tried starting STS 3.6.1 on commandline. I am also getting the message about m2e/statelocation. But it starts up normally after that. So the message probably has nothing to do with the problem you are experiencing. If trying oracle JDK doesn't help, try to determine if a java process is running (use command jps and/or 'ps -fe | grep java'), try to determine the eclipse process (if its running) and collect a stackdump with command 'jstack'. It's possible the process did start but is somehow deadlocked. The stacktrace may help determine why.

Comment: I installed Oracle JDK 1.7.0_67, however still getting stuck with the same issue. Yes java is running and so do Spring tool suite. I have collected the stackdump using 'jstack' command . How to analyze it ?

Comment: Please find the stackdump file for STS here - [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Nnd496GlTJbGV0Nmgza2s1OUU/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: There is surprisingly little going on in the stack dump. I would have expected to sees something being 'busy' doing something, or a deadlock situation. But I don't see that. I don't know what is going on. Maybe the STS install is corrupted. Try restarting it with '-clean' option. another thing you can try is set the environment variable 'SWT_GTK3=0'. Maybe it is a rendering issues with GTK3. If neither of this works, try downloading a new copy of STS.

Comment: Another place to look for error messages is the eclipse error log. It inside your workspace folder in file called '.log'. Maybe there is something in there that explains what's going on. Delete the log before starting STS so we know which messages are 'new'. Post the messages somewhere and I can take a look.

Comment: how much ram do u have free? in terminal type top then see first few lines

Comment: I found the solution in this link. https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/eclipse-mars-freezes-after-splash-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set mozilla as your browser in STS. To do that add

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

at the end of `STS.ini`.